# Simple cloud code editor (+ python interpreter)

Tags: text-editor, python, cloud-service

I'm teaching a very introductory weekend computer class to high schools students and am looking for an editor for them to use. Here's what I'm looking for:

- Python support, with syntax highlighting and an interpreter.
- Online (can be used entirely in the browser)
- Cloud storage (i.e., don't need Dropbox or similar, and don't need to be able to store on the local computer, which they won't be able to do)
- Simple, if at all possible. It doesn't need bells and whistles. It needs to run very simple Python code, and that's it. Since we don't have long with the students, we don't want to spend the time wading through unnecessary features. We won't be doing much more complicated than is covered in Codecademy.
- **Edit:** Adding in that it must have console-interaction (like repl.it)

Things like Cloud9 and Codeanywhere are way too complicated for this and don't seem to let you store directly to your account for the service.

Comment: Perhaps the [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)? See ["Running a notebook server"](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/notebook/public_server.html).

Comment: Not a good option since you have to install iPython and set up the server.

Comment: Setting up the server isn't hard as explained there, as for the installation there Python distributions that make it easier, e.g. [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/),

Comment: http://runnable.com/ looks perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/) is perfect.

You simply make an account, and go to the 'new code' section. Make the code private, and when you compile it, it gets saved to your account.

Here's a sample of what you'll see after saving (look at stdout for output):

[image]

Features:

- free
- syntax highlighting (after clicking 'ideone it')
- saves to your account

Comment: That would've been my first choice, too, and I still favor it somewhat over Pythonfiddle; however, the syntax is higlighted, it seems, only when you run the code, not during the initial edit? I'll need to run it in a desktop browser, it seems it doesn't favor my ipad's Safari...I cannot edit the code once launched, maybe it does highlight it when attempting to, my apologies if I disseminated false info.

Comment: @elderelder It highlights as you type. It's probably because you're on your iPad that it doesn't for you.

Comment: I stand corrected then, and most likely I'd go myself with Ideone. Upvote.

Comment: @elderelder Yeah, I've found ideone to be helpful for the past year or so, as I've been learning Python. Whenever I came across a piece of code, I'd go there and test it, and see how it works. And thanks :)

Comment: Although, I like that pythonfiddle gives you autocomplete, so +1

Comment: My problem with this (and with Pythonfiddle) is that there is no terminal to interact with, which is essential (lessons involve making text-based games that require input via the console). If I could get Ideone-like account/code management with interaction like Repl, I'd be thrilled. Currently I'm looking at Koding, which is WAY overkill but is the only thing I've found with account saving and console interaction.

Comment: @Pterosaur Try http://repl.it/. Although you can't make an account, you can always save the code and access it via a link...

Answer (score 2):

[Pythonfiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/) is a cloud-based IDE.

What I like about it is that it is, indeed very simple to use.

- syntax highlighting
- code completion assistance
- ability to save
- share your work
- import code from other sites
- free

[image]